# python - Identify variable in similar sentences

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, similarity, text

I'm looking to solve the following problem: I have a list of similar sentences as my dataset, and I want to be able to type a new sentence, which is also similar to the sentences in my dataset and then highlight the parts of the sentence which are varying. For example,

This is the set I have:

```
I want to eat an apple
I want to eat an ice cream
I want to drink coffee
I want to eat a pizza
I want to puke ginger
```

These sentences are similar but they have some varying parts. The two main variables in these sentences are the `action` (eat, drink, puke) and the `food` (apple, ice cream, coffee, pizza, ginger).

Now if I type in a new sentence say `I want to drink cola` I want my model to identify `drink` and `cola` as the variables in this sentence.

At this point, I don't really care about the semantics that much. I will work on that later. Even if the sentence is `I want to hug a table`, all I want to do is identify `hug` and `table` as variables.